# how to only get title of subsite and not display title of app also

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, restore

right now this code writes out the subsites title and relativeurl, but it also includes my title of my app, but i only want to display the subsites title and not title of the app also,

Any sugesstions what i should do?
Here is my code

```
 function execCrossDomainRequest() {
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        var queryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/webs?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl&@target='" +hostweburl + "'" ;

        executor.executeAsync(
             {
                 url: queryUrl,
                 method: "GET",
                 headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                 success: successHandler,
                 error: errorHandler
             }
                 );
                    }
                        })
function successHandler(data) {
$("#subSiteTitle").keypress(function () {
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
    var dataArr = $.makeArray(jsonObject.d.results);
    var resultArr = $.map(dataArr, function (item) {

        return { label: item.Title + " (" + item.ServerRelativeUrl + ")", value: item.ServerRelativeUrl };

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The app hosted in SharePoint creates a sub site under the Host Site. This sub site is called App Web and it has the same name as that of the app. A filter needs to be added to the `REST` query so that this app web is the not included in the result set. Suppose the name of the app web is "App1", the filter will look like this:

```
$filter= Title ne 'App1'
```

In your case the REST Url will be:

```
var queryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/webs?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl&$filter= Title ne 'NameOFApp'&@target='" +hostweburl + "'" ;
```

Replace `'NameOFApp'` with name of your app.

**UPDATE**

Since you can have 'n' number of Apps in a Host site and obviously hard coding name of the app in filter is not an option. The other way to not include app webs in result set is to use `WebTemplate` in the filter. The filter to exclude App webs is:

```
$filter=WebTemplate ne 'APP'
```

Comment: Alright but if i dont not the name of the app, because when i have 2 apps its displays 2 titles. so if the user adds more apps it will be displayed?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you. Can you elaborate.

Comment: I have two apps, and 2 subsites, all four are displayed. when using $filter= Title ne i must now the the name of the app as u have replayed. But if the user and 1 more app so its 3 apps and 2 subsites how should my filter know the name of the app? when i hard code what the name is?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: alright i dont got it to work i get bad request when using $filter=WebTemplate ne 'AppWeb'

Comment: Add `WebTemplate` in select statement along with `Title` and `ServerRelativeUrl` and remove it from the filter. Then check what is the value of `WebTemplate` returned through a tool like fiddler for the app web. `'AppWeb'` may not be the correct name of the template.